# Convert a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is my multidimensional array.The first index array is data for a user, each sub array contain the properties for a user i.e name, Ideally i want to break this array to have such an array as below.

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [First Name] => dahn
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Event Name] => TESTING OUT THE EVENTBRITE PHP API
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Last Name] => king
                )

        )

    [2] => Array........
```

The array i want to be able to generate is as such

```
    
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [First Name] => dahn 
            [Event Name] => Testing Out Eventbrite PHP API
            [Last Name] => king
         )

    [1] => Array
        (
```

Thanks in advance. A link or anything to point me in the right direction will be highly appreciated

Comment: Iterate over the array using a nested `foreach` loop and create the new array.

Comment: I can't seem to find the link between the two arrays =,=

Comment: @I can Has Cheezburger they are not relate just the format i want to produce a similar.

Comment: @AmalMurali thats the far my am able to nest my foreach ave tried to nest it but i guess there is something am doing thats wrong since...is there away i can play around with php array_map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function convert($array){
    $new = array();

    foreach($array AS $arr){
        $n = Array();
        foreach($arr as $arr2){
            foreach($arr2 AS $key => $val){
              $n[$key] = $val;

            }
        }
        $new[] = $n;
    }

    return $new;
}
?>
```